# Debugging a very difficult-to-reproduce Java web app issue (frontend)

Tags: java, css, nginx, tomcat7, internet-explorer-11

I have a Java web app that deploys as a WAR to Tomcat 7.0.41 (`myapp.war`). I noticed that when I deploy the WAR to a Tomcat that lives in one part of our network, the web pages display perfectly fine. However, and this only happens in IE 11, if I take the exact same WAR and deploy it to the exact same version/Chef-configured-instance of a Tomcat server that lives in another part of our network, the page stylings look way different and completely wrong. Again, this is specific to IE11 and the location in the network that the app is served from. If I go to the app in IE 11 from a "good" location on the network, the frontend renders perfectly fine. Or if I view the app from a "bad" location on the network, but in a non-IE browser, again all is well.

I have a feeling that we might have some IT proxy (nginx, etc.) that is preventing Tomcat from serving certain CSS/JS files, and so the end result is a partially-complete frontend that looks all wonky in the browser. And somehow, this only crops up in IE 11.

I have (sort of) confirmed this by viewing the source of all my HTML, JS and CSS files and copying them to files in a local folder. I then open up one of the HTML files (locally) in a browser and the site displays perfectly.

The problem here is that my JS files use a bunch of open source JS libraries. And those libraries have dependencies on other libraries. So on and so forth, and the dependency graph is pretty huge. It's tough for me to tell which files are not being downloaded properly/completely.

Here's the kicker: if I add in `html5shiv` to my app then the problem goes away entirely, no matter which browser (IE or not) or what location in the network I choose. However adding html5shiv breaks other things in my app, and for reasons outside the context of this question, can't be used.

Anyone have any idea how I could troubleshoot/fix this? Why would this only be affecting IE 11 and not other browsers? Why is html5shiv solving this?!?

Comment: 1. Do you get errors in the console using the "developer" tools of IE? 2. Did you check the rendering mode the browser is choosing? 3. What happens in older versions of the browser? 4. Did you check the browser security (trusted pages etc.) settings?

Comment: Thanks @NicoO (+1) : (1) No errors with developer tools, (2) How do I check rendering mode? (3) Displays perfectly fine in IE9 and IE10, and (4) No issues with security/trust. Thoughts? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to start using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

What it does is capture all network traffic and allow you to view it exactly as it was sent/received by your network card.

What I would do is capture the complete traffic that occurs between your computer and the server in the location where it is working, when you visit the webpage that has the problem. Then repeat that for the server that is not working.

You will then have the complete traffic and can compare them side by side. Even if it doesn't tell you the cause of the problem Wireshark will tell you where the difference is occurring in the packets that are sent by the two different servers.

You could also do it the other way round by running TCPDump (with command like `tcpdump -i eth0 -w file.cap -s 0` to get the complete packets, rather than just the first X bytes) on the server, to capture the packets sent, and then viewing the capture in Wireshark.

> "Does Wireshark offer such file-level abstractions or is it all nitty-gritty, byte-level output I need to read?"

Kind of both. Basically once you have the stream in front of you, you are able to see the individual requests starting by looking for GET entries in the packets.

[image]

Once you've identified where a file starts, you can right-click on that packet, choose follow TCP stream and it will give you a summarised view of that TCP stream:

[image]

If you need the detailed difference between the files, it will be there....but tbh it's probably going to be something obvious like a file being completely truncated or mangled, rather than just a byte or two being wrong in one of the files.

Comment: Thanks @Danack (+1) - I think I'll try the Wireshark route, although I know its a true skill to read a TCP dump and I'm worried I won't know what to look for. Once I get two captures (that I compare against), it would be nice to see some feature in Wireshark that shows that, say, a *blah.js* file downloaded perfectly fine in one dump (the dump of the communication where the pages load correctly), but the *blah.js* didn't download in the "bad" dump. Does Wireshark offer such file-level abstractions or is it all nitty-gritty, byte-level output I need to read? Thanks again!